# Continue running script once jquery ajax call is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a click function that has a popup window that I need to open once the ajax call is successful. I have tried setting async: false. I tried putting the popup in the ajax call but that makes the popup blocked by the browser. And my last attempt was to set a timeout until the ajax call completes and each with no luck. Any suggestions???

```
var currentStatus = "false";
var success = "false";

function waitForSuccess(){
    if (success == "false"){
        var t = setTimeout("waitForSuccess()", 300);
    }
    else{
        stopTimer(t);
        return "true";
    }
}
function stopTimer(t){
    clearTimeout(t);
}

 function checkReps(clicked){
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "chat_new_files/chat_new.php",
            success: function(data){
                       success = "true";
                    }
      });

$('#chatT').live('click', function (event) {
         success = "false";
             checkReps("true");
         var changed = waitForSuccess();
        if(changed == "true"){
                  BG.startChatWithIssueId('0', true);    //THIS IS THE POPUP
        }
});
```

I am thinking that my logic for this last attempt with the setTimeout is messed up. So any ideas on how to fix this or a brand new idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating things:

```
$('#chatT').live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "chat_new_files/chat_new.php",
        success: function(data){
            BG.startChatWithIssueId('0', true);
        }
    });
});
```

As far as the browser popup blocker issue, a simple work-around is to create a div which acts as a popup container, like `<div id="popup"></div>`. Inside that div you can add an iframe with the url being the same of what your oldskool popup was. Initially, give that div the CSS `#popup { display:none; position:relative; z-index:99999; /* etc...*/ }` Then in your click event, you simply `show()` or `fadeIn()` that div.

Example, check out [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) - on the demo page, click the link that reads "Outside Webpage (Iframe)"

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! this works like a charm. I didn't think of this because I have to have an ajax call separate from the click but I just put another one inside the click function exactly as you showed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Open the popup in the `success:` function for the ajax call.  That is the only place that you both know that the ajax call has completely successfully and that you have access to the data that is returned from the ajax call.

Do not use timers to try to guess when the ajax function is done.

Comment: But if I put the popup in the ajax call the browsers popup blocker blocks it.

Comment: All attempts to open a popup window asynchronously will likely run into popup blockers.  The only work-around I know of is to open the popup window upon click with some default "loading..." content in it and then fill in the data later when the ajax call completes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback that you can call in `success` of `$.ajax()`. Then open you popup window in the callback.

```
 function checkReps(clicked){
      $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "chat_new_files/chat_new.php",
            success: function(data){
                       success = "true";
                       openPopup();
                    }
      });
```

Comment: I tried this but the popup blocker in the browser still blocked it.

Comment: Then use something like jQuery Modal dialog in `openPopup().`:http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to block popups that aren't originated from an event handler because those popups tend not to be user-initiated (duh).  To get around this, you have 2 choices:

1. launch the popup immedately and have its content be filler, probably
   including some sort of http://ajaxload.info spinner gif
2. avoid opening a new window, and instead put your content in a 'modal' div that you 
   show and hide as required.